# How to make future posts visible to selected visitors without login

Tags: user-access, password

I run a website that I run stories that deal with other people's work and I want to allow them to view the specific post dealing with them, but without them having a wordpress login.

I tried making it password protected but it shows up on the website, and I would not like people seeing it, even if it is just a title and picture.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're best bet might be to make a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). By default, a new post type is hidden from the WordPress archives and blog pages, so no one would see it on accident, but you could still easily link to it with the URL.

You could make a post type called something like 'Work', and each time you make a new post of that type, it wouldn't be displayed in your website. Other than being hidden, you could make it function just like any other post or page.

If you aren't comfortable with code, you might want to look at the plugin More Types, which lets you make extra post types from the WP admin. If you can handle some copy and pasting, check out the [Themergency generator](http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/).

Comment: Here is a link to More Types, which SE wouldn't let me include for fear that I was a spammer: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-types/

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly secure, but you could simply use private posts and provide the URL to the individual.